# How to Avoid onClick callback being called multiple times Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

While testing my app I realized that if a user pressed the `FloatingActionButton` quickly, several times, the onClick call back could be fired multiple times. In my case, this caused the backstack being popped multiple times, as the `onPopBackStack` callback bubbles up to the `NavHost` where it has access to the `navController` and ivokes the `popBackStack` method.

```
fun AddEditTodoScreen(onPopBackStack: () -> Unit, viewModel: AddEditTodoViewModel = viewModel()) {

    var isNavigating by remember{
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
        viewModel.uiEvent.collect{event : UiEvent ->
            when(event){
                is UiEvent.PopBackStack -> onPopBackStack
                else -> Unit
            }
        }
    }

    Scaffold(floatingActionButton = {
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
            if(!isNavigating){
                isNavigating = !isNavigating
                onPopBackStack()
            }
        }) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Check, contentDescription = "Check")
        }
```

Currently I'm just setting a `isNavigating` to true when the `FloatingActionButton` is first clicked and if clicked again, it checks if the `isNavigating` flag is set to true, if so it does nothing. What would be a better way, if any, to address this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Navigation already tells you if you're navigating to a new destination: the `Lifecycle` of the `NavBackStackEntry` is synchronously changed when you call `navigate`, moving you down from the `RESUMED` state.

Therefore if you want to avoid handling clicks after you've already started navigating to another screen, you'd want to check the `LocalLifecycleOwner`'s state:

```
// This corresponds with the NavBackStackEntry
// associated with this screen
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
    // Get the current state of the Lifecycle
    val currentState = lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState

    // And ignore click events when you've started navigating
    // to another screen
    if (currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) {
        onPopBackStack()
    }
}
```