# How to prevent navigation to both paths when clicking buttons at the same time?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have 3 screens on my app (`MainScreen`, `Screen1` and `Screen2`).
On the `MainScreen` there are two buttons used to navigate on other screens.

This is the current app:

[image]

My problem is, if I click simultaneously on both buttons, both destinations are stacked in the backstack. I don't want this behavior, I want to open only one screen.
In other words the `MainScreen` must always remain on the backstack, and there can only be one of the two screens (`Screen1`, `Screen2`) above the `MainScreen`. How to do that?

Here is my current code:

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
enum class Routes {
    MainScreen, Screen1, Screen2
}

sealed class UiEvent {
    data class Navigate(val route: String): UiEvent()
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = Routes.MainScreen.name
                ) {
                    composable(route = Routes.MainScreen.name) {
                        MainScreen(onNavigate = {
                            navController.navigate(route = it.route) {
                                launchSingleTop = true
                            }
                        },)
                    }
                    composable(route = Routes.Screen1.name) {
                        Screen1()
                    }
                    composable(route = Routes.Screen2.name) {
                        Screen2()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    onNavigate: (UiEvent.Navigate) -> Unit,
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.uiEvent.collectLatest { uiEvent ->
            when (uiEvent) {
                is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                    onNavigate(uiEvent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                val currentState = lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState
                if (currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) {
                    viewModel.navigateTo(Routes.Screen1)
                }
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Screen1")
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                val currentState = lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState
                if (currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) {
                    viewModel.navigateTo(Routes.Screen2)
                }
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Screen2")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen1() { Text(text = "Screen 1") }

@Composable
fun Screen2() { Text(text = "Screen 2") }
```

**MainViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiEvent = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val uiEvent = _uiEvent.receiveAsFlow()

    fun navigateTo(route: Routes) {
        sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(route.name))
    }

    private fun sendUiEvent(event: UiEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiEvent.send(event)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---**EDIT**---

I modified the code and description, and I updated the image.

The problem exists in 2 cases:

- if I quickly press one button and then the other (**solved** using [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76386604/19467294))
- if I press both buttons at the same time (**unsolved**, as you can see in the image above)

Comment: Please don't use any of those debouncing kind of solutions when Navigation already gives you a 100% signal to avoid clicks when you've already navigated to another screen by checking the Lifecycle to ensure it is RESUMED as per the duplicate question.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't very clear in explaining the problem, I only showed the problem by quickly pressing one button and then the other, but the problem persists if I press both buttons at the same time. I updated the question, could you please reopen the question? Or maybe it doesn't work because I didn't implement your solution correctly? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Both clicks are handled in the same single main thread, so one is always going to happen before the other one (they can't both be simultaneously running). Can you confirm you're on the latest version of Navigation (2.7.6)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I hadn't implemented navigation, now I added it, but the problem is still not solved, these are my dependencies: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/cJkcecPV).

Comment: You wrapped the wrong callbacks - you need to wrap your call to `navController.navigate` in your `MainActivity` - that's what is synchronously changing the state (thus preventing handling the second event).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension like this

```
fun View.setOnDebouncedClickListener(action: () -> Unit) {
    val actionDebouncer =
        ActionDebouncer(action)

    // This is the only place in the project where we should actually use setOnClickListener
    setOnClickListener {
        actionDebouncer.notifyAction()
    }
}

fun View.removeOnDebouncedClickListener() {
    setOnClickListener(null)
    isClickable = false
}

private class ActionDebouncer(private val action: () -> Unit) {

    companion object {
        const val DEBOUNCE_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS = 600L
    }

    private var lastActionTime = 0L

    fun notifyAction() {
        val now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()

        val millisecondsPassed = now - lastActionTime
        val actionAllowed = millisecondsPassed > DEBOUNCE_INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS
        lastActionTime = now

        if (actionAllowed) {
            action.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```